# motivation letter for phd application when my master major is not a perfect match, e.g I don't have domain knowledge

Tags: phd, application-cover-letter, motivation

There is a PhD project I am interested in.

This project is about computer vision in the biological area. The master degree they are looking for is 'Photonics, (bio)physics or similar'. The machine learning knowledge is an advantage, but not required. My master degree is computer science, and I have knowledge in machine learning, and my master thesis project is about optimisation algorithms.

What should I focus when I write the motivation letter for this position?

The most important reason is I really want to do something related to computer vision. I read a news that inspired me to do a phd. Could I also include this in my motivation? This news is more related to the AI-tech application in the art painting area.

Comment: Have you done anything informal to gain the required background or are you truly without domain knowledge?

Comment: only basic biology knowledge in high school.